# Use leader key mapping in another mapping - not working

Tags: key-bindings, leader

I'm trying to use a leader mapping in another mapping. But nothing happens when I attempt to use the second mapping. I'm quite sure I've done this before. What's going wrong?

This mapping finds the next sentence, roughly speaking, as expected:

```
:noremap <leader>se /\v>[.;:?!](\s<bar>$)<CR>
```

I want to use that mapping in another, but nothing happens - as in, for example:

```
noremap <leader>sb \se
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `noremap` command, which doesn't expand mappings on the expansion, so it won't recognize the `\se` which is a mapping itself.

See [`:help :nore`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Anore), which says:

> Map the key sequence `{lhs}` to `{rhs}` for the modes
> where the map command applies.  **Disallow mapping of
> `{rhs}`, to avoid nested and recursive mappings.**  Often
> used to redefine a command.

In your case, you want the regular version of the `:map` command, to be able to recognize mappings in the replacement. So you can fix this with:

```
:map <leader>sb \se
```